# Syntax error in spatial query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgis

I wrote a function for found all pois around a track

controller :

```
def index
  @track = Track.friendly.find(params[:track_id])
  @tracks = Track.where(way_id: @track.id)
  @way = Way.find(1)
  @poi_start = Poi.find(@way.point_start)
  @pois = @track.pois.sleepsAndtowns
  @pois = @way.poi_around_track_from(@poi_start, 50000, @pois)
end
```

way.rb

```
def poi_around_track_from(poi, dist, pois)
  around_sql = <<-SQL
  SELECT
  ST_DWithin(
    ST_LineSubstring(
    way.path,
    ST_LineLocatePoint(way.path, pta.lonlat::geometry) + #{dist} / ST_Length(way.path::geography),
    ST_LineLocatePoint(way.path, pta.lonlat::geometry) + 100000 / ST_Length(way.path::geography)
  ),
  ptb.lonlat,
  2000) is true as pois
  FROM ways way, pois pta, pois ptb
  WHERE way.id = #{self.id}
    and pta.id = #{poi.id}
    and ptb.id = #{pois.ids}
  SQL
  Poi.find_by_sql(around_sql).pois
end
```

This function return :
syntax error at or near "["
LINE 13:       and ptb.id = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

What's wrong, how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using standard sql to build the query, (not the ActiveRecord), you will have to use the standard `IN` clues with `where`

It looks like `pois.ids` is returning an array, so, you will have to turn it to a string in the format as below

`[1,2] #=> (1,2)`

Change,

```
WHERE way.id = #{self.id}
    and pta.id = #{poi.id}
    and ptb.id = #{pois.ids}
```

to

```
WHERE way.id = #{self.id}
    and pta.id = #{poi.id}
    and ptb.id IN (#{pois.ids.join(',')})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change pois.ids as @semeera207 wrote to string or go another way and compare ptb.id to pois.ids as an array.

```
  WHERE way.id = #{self.id}
and pta.id = #{poi.id}
and array[ptb.id] && #{pois.ids}
```

To make it faster create gin index

```
Create index on pois using gin((array[id]));
```

Comment: Thanks sameera207 and Grzegorz Grabek for your help.
I know gist index but no gin index.... I don't know how it work.  Could you explain ?

Comment: @Ben Best info is here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/gin.html